# MongoDB could not connect local server

Tags: 12.04, installation, accessibility, mongodb

I had mongdb installed and evrything was working fine. I wanted to delete the mongodb lock. By mistake the directory /var/lib/mongodb/ got deleted.

So, I uninstalled mongo db and installed again. But now i always keep getting this error:

```
Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017 at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:145
exception: connect fail
```

The error remains same even if I try to login from terminal or rockmongo or my application.
I am using ubuntu12.04 and have latest version of mongo.

Comment: Have you seen this => http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16120397/errr-mongo-jsl112-error-couldnt-connect-to-server-127-0-0-127017-at-src-mon

Comment: Yes..but in my /var/lib/mongodb there is no mongodb.lock.

Comment: The file could be in a different path or it could be named `mongo.lock`

Comment: What you get when you run this `/usr/local/mongodb/bin/mongod`?

Comment: I get bash: /usr/local/mongodb/bin/mongod: No such file or directory

Comment: FYI: from the 10gen repo it will be in /usr/bin/mongod not /usr/local

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get the connect failure because the server is not running.  Run this:

```
sudo service mongodb restart
```

If that does not succeed then you will need to examine the log files for the server to see what is stopping it from starting.  You can find the log in `/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log` and if it is not an obvious cause, then please add the relevant snippet to your question and I'd be happy to take a look.

If I were to guess based on your description, I would suspect you did not set the correct permissions on `/var/lib/mongodb` - when you recreated it.  It should look like this:

```
drwxr-xr-x 4 mongodb mongodb 4096 Nov 26 18:52 mongodb
```

If it has incorrect permissions, then you can fix it with the following command:

```
sudo chown -R mongodb:mongodb /var/lib/mongodb
```

Comment: mongod not mongodb ?

Comment: that depends on what package you use to install, it can be either but it is generally one or the other